# ServiceStack Ormlite CreateTable using String expressions Inheriting an interface

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am still new to C#, ServiceStack and Ormlite, so please be gentle with me.

Suppose I would like to create multiple tables that have the same properties. I would inherit all these tables with an interface class called `IParentTable`:

```
public interface IParentTable
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string OldValue { get; set; }
    string NewValue { get; set; }
    string DoneBy { get; set; }
    DateTimeOffset DoneOn { get; set; }
}
```

There is no problem to just inherit it and create a concrete class:

```
public someclass : IParentTable
```

and thus create a table in database using the the clean and sleek SS Ormlite API:

`db.CreateTable<someclass>`

Question now is, I would like to create many of these tables on the fly. Due to some constraints, the only "resource" I have got is a string `tableName`. So is there any way I can create a table using `db.CreateTable` that will create a table whose name is `tableName` at the same time having all the fields in `IParentTable`?

I have looked into the `Alias` attribute too, but that is not practical since I do not code out the concrete class. So the combined problem will be:

Given a string `tableName`, am I able to construct a class that inherits `IParentTable` (whose class name is `tableName`, maybe?) so that this class can be used as a parameter in the squarebrackets of `db.CreateTable<>`?

I tried to workaround with generics but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: See this answer for how to [extend OrmLite with extension methods overloads that takes a tableName](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24967751/85785).

Comment: Thanks @mythz! Still as swift as ever, responding queries within hours. (Y)