# Create table with custom name dynamically and insert with custom table name

Tags: servicestack

I want to create the table with custom name but I cannot find the sample code. I notice the only way to create table is by generic type like db.CreateTable(). May I know if there is a way to create the table name dynamically instead of using Alias? The reason is because sometime we want to store the same object type into different tables like 2015_january_activity, 2015_february_activity.

Apart from this, the db.Insert also very limited to object type. Is there anyway to insert by passing in the table name?

I think these features are very important as it exists in NoSQL solution for long and it's very flexible. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OrmLite is primarily a code-first ORM which uses typed POCO's to create and query the schema of matching RDMBS tables. It also supports executing Custom SQL using the [Custom SQL API's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpressions-with-custom-sql-apis).

One option to use a different table name is to change the Alias at runtime as [seen in this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24967751/85785) where you can create custom extension methods to modify the name of the table, e.g:

```
public static class GenericTableExtensions 
{
    static object ExecWithAlias<T>(string table, Func<object> fn)
    {
        var modelDef = typeof(T).GetModelMetadata();
        lock (modelDef) {
            var hold = modelDef.Alias;
            try {
                modelDef.Alias = table;
                return fn();
            }
            finally {
                modelDef.Alias = hold;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void DropAndCreateTable<T>(this IDbConnection db, string table) {
        ExecWithAlias<T>(table, () => { db.DropAndCreateTable<T>(); return null; });
    }

    public static long Insert<T>(this IDbConnection db, string table, T obj, bool selectIdentity = false) {
        return (long)ExecWithAlias<T>(table, () => db.Insert(obj, selectIdentity));
    }

    public static List<T> Select<T>(this IDbConnection db, string table, Func<SqlExpression<T>, SqlExpression<T>> expression) {
        return (List<T>)ExecWithAlias<T>(table, () => db.Select(expression));
    }

    public static int Update<T>(this IDbConnection db, string table, T item, Expression<Func<T, bool>> where) {
        return (int)ExecWithAlias<T>(table, () => db.Update(item, where));
    }
}
```

These extension methods provide additional API's that let you change the name of the table used, e.g:

```
var tableName = "TableA"'
db.DropAndCreateTable<GenericEntity>(tableName);

db.Insert(tableName, new GenericEntity { Id = 1, ColumnA = "A" });

var rows = db.Select<GenericEntity>(tableName, q =>
    q.Where(x => x.ColumnA == "A"));

rows.PrintDump();

db.Update(tableName, new GenericEntity { ColumnA = "B" },
    where: q => q.ColumnA == "A");

rows = db.Select<GenericEntity>(tableName, q => 
    q.Where(x => x.ColumnA == "B"));

rows.PrintDump();
```

This example is also available in the [GenericTableExpressions.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/Expression/GenericTableExpressions.cs) integration test.